# How do I move iTunes properly to a new computer? (music, multiple iPads and their apps, etc.)

Tags: windows-7, itunes, ipad

Current Setup

- iTunes on a dying laptop (Windows 7)
- Music purchased through iTunes and partially synced to multiple iPads
- iPads registered through iTunes
- apps downloaded directly to iPads
- iPads OS's not all current yet
- all of the above is on one account

What I want to do

- Upgrade all OS to latest on iPads
- Correctly transfer all apps, music, settings to a new computer (Windows 7)
- Not lose any information or purchases of anything
- Ensure I don't have to re-register iPads, etc.

My first thought is to install iTunes to the latest version on the new computer and also make sure the old computer has the latest version. Upgrade all iPads before transfer.

I have not found a definitive source on how to do this without losing something in the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following works, as I've moved iTunes between computers many times in the past.

1. Install the latest version of iTunes on both PCs
2. Copy the C:\Users[your-name]\Music\iTunes\ folder from PC A to PC B
3. Plug iPads into new PC and re-sync

You may need to authorise the new PC with your iTunes account (up to 5 authorisations per year).

If this doesn't work - simply re-sync the iPads back on PC A. I'd also recommend running a backup of them on PC A before switching PC and even copying the iTunes folder to a 3rd location in case. If your Music isn't within the same folder, you may need to manually edit the iTunes file or re-import the Music.

Comment: That should be the correct procedure.